# Convert time string ("hours:minute") to date object

Tags: javascript, date, time, ember.js

Here is time string with hours and minutes (e.g. "03:37"). I want to update date object that time and create date object in ember JS. Help me with this. The time goes by 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do the following:

```
const time = "03:37";
const [ h, m ] = time.split(":");
const ms = new Date().setHours(h,m);
const date = new Date(ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the substring() function to extract the hours and minutes. Then use the setHours() function to assign them to any date object.

```js
const today = new Date();

const timeString = "03:37";

// Use the substring() function to extract hours and minutes
const hours = timeString.substring(0,2);
const minutes = timeString.substring(3,5);

// Use the setHours() function to assign hours and minutes
// to the "today" date object
const modifiedDate = new Date(today.setHours(hours, minutes));

console.log(modifiedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is time string with Days , hours and minutes (e.g. "56 days 05:55:00"). you can convert into time using below function

```js
function convertStringToTime(durationString: string): any {
  const parts = durationString.split(' ');

  const daysIndex = parts.findIndex(part => part === 'days');
  const days = parseInt(parts[daysIndex - 1]);

  const timeParts = parts[daysIndex + 1].split(':');
  const hours = parseInt(timeParts[0]);
  const minutes = parseInt(timeParts[1]);

  return { days, hours, minutes };
}


/* And For access this function this way you can do */

const durationString = "56 days 05:55:00";
const parsedDuration = convertStringToTime(durationString);

console.log(parsedDuration); // { days: 56, hours: 5, minutes: 55 }
```

**Check Output in browser console**